# How does the Translation thing work in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, translation

It gives me an error on this code:

```
from translate import Translator

translator = Translator(to_lang='en') 

text = input("Enter what should be translated: ")

translation = translator.translate(text) 
print(f"{translation.text}")
```

and the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
 File "main.py", line 12 in <module>
  print(f"{translation.text}") 
Attribute Error: 'str' object has no attribute to 'text'
```

Please help me if you can.
Thank you for reading my question

I tried for a long time. But it just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Please provide a link to the documentation page of the `translate` module you use.

Comment: simply `print(translation)`

Answer (score 1):

Just simply use `translation` without `text`

```py
print(f"{translation}")
```